# Why do I get a SocketTimeoutException when trying to connect to ElasticCache using Jedis?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, redis, amazon-elasticache

I am trying to connect my Spring Boot project to ElasticCache Redis in AWS. However, I get this error:

```
Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.cache.type=redis
spring.redis.host=*****.*****.****.****.cache.amazonaws.com
spring.redis.port=6379
spring.redis.prefix=testing
```

**RedisConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class RedisConfig {

    @Value("${spring.redis.host}")
    private String redisHostName;

    @Value("${spring.redis.port}")
    private int redisPort;

    @Value("${spring.redis.prefix}")
    private String redisPrefix;

    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        System.out.println(redisHostName);
        System.out.println(redisPort);
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisHostName, redisPort);
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
    }
    
    @Bean(value = "redisTemplate")
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        return redisTemplate;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "cacheManager") // Default cache manager is infinite
    public CacheManager cacheManager(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        return RedisCacheManager.builder(redisConnectionFactory).cacheDefaults(RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().prefixKeysWith(redisPrefix)).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "cacheManager1Hour")
    public CacheManager cacheManager1Hour(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        Duration expiration = Duration.ofHours(1);
        return RedisCacheManager.builder(redisConnectionFactory)
                .cacheDefaults(RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().prefixKeysWith(redisPrefix).entryTtl(expiration)).build();
    }

}
```

**UserDetailsServiceImpl.java**

```
    @Override
    @Cacheable(value = "userdetails", key="{#userId}", cacheManager = "cacheManager1Hour")
    public User getUserDetails(String userId) {
    
        User user =userDAO.getUserbyID(userId);
        
        return user;
         
    }
```

On Server startup, it loads fine and starts without any error or warning.

But on invoking the API I get the below error:

```
Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
```

The Java Stack Trace says something like this:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:476) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:218) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:394) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at redis.clients.jedis.DefaultJedisSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultJedisSocketFactory.java:80) ~[jedis-3.7.1.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:226) ~[jedis-3.7.1.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:140) ~[jedis-3.7.1.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:310) ~[jedis-3.7.1.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.initializeFromClientConfig(BinaryJedis.java:88) ~[jedis-3.7.1.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.<init>(BinaryJedis.java:293) ~[jedis-3.7.1.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.<init>(Jedis.java:169) ~[jedis-3.7.1.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:177) ~[jedis-3.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:889) ~[commons-pool2-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:424) ~[commons-pool2-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:349) ~[commons-pool2-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at redis.clients.jedis.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:75) ~[jedis-3.7.1.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:370) ~[jedis-3.7.1.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:15) ~[jedis-3.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:272) ~[spring-data-redis-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:476) ~[spring-data-redis-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.DefaultRedisCacheWriter.execute(DefaultRedisCacheWriter.java:238) ~[spring-data-redis-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.DefaultRedisCacheWriter.get(DefaultRedisCacheWriter.java:109) ~[spring-data-redis-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.lookup(RedisCache.java:88) ~[spring-data-redis-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cache.support.AbstractValueAdaptingCache.get(AbstractValueAdaptingCache.java:58) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doGet(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:73) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findInCaches(CacheAspectSupport.java:554) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findCachedItem(CacheAspectSupport.java:519) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:401) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:345) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.spacebasic.dataservices.dashboard.DashboardServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d5511fa9.getDashboardDetailsApp(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at com.spacebasic.dataservices.dashboard.DashboardController.getDashboardDetailsApp(DashboardController.java:46) ~[main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at io.sentry.spring.SentryUserFilter.doFilterInternal(SentryUserFilter.java:56) ~[sentry-spring-5.6.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.spacebasic.dataservices.util.JwtRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtRequestFilter.java:55) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:109) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at io.sentry.spring.tracing.SentryTracingFilter.doFilterInternal(SentryTracingFilter.java:69) ~[sentry-spring-5.6.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at io.sentry.spring.SentrySpringFilter.doFilterInternal(SentrySpringFilter.java:57) ~[sentry-spring-5.6.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_301]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_301]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_301]
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: Does your application have access to your Redis cache? Have you checked your EC2 security groups? This is 99.99% an access issue between your application and Redis.

Comment: Right now I am trying to connect from my localhost. I am yet to deploy on EC2

Comment: Your local host won’t have access to your Redis instance by default, as per security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Your local machine will not have access to ElastiCache, a service designed to be used internally within your VPC. External access is discouraged due to the latency of Internet traffic and security concerns.

If you need local access however for test or development purposes, you can use a VPN as per docs.

Refer to [Amazon ElastiCache for Redis User Guide - Accessing your cluster or replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/accessing-elasticache.html#access-from-outside-aws) for more information on how to allow external access to your Elasticache nodes.