# Can't connect to AWS ElastiCache Redis cluster in .NET 6 application

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, redis, .net-6.0, amazon-elasticache

I have created a .NET application and trying to connect to a AWS Redis cluster but I am receiving this exception:

```
It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s). UnableToConnect on *****.cache.amazonaws.com:6379/Interactive, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: BeginConnectAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 0s ago, last-write: 0s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 47s ago, v: 2.2.4.27433
```

Here is my code and the way I have configured the service.

```
public class DistributedCacheProvider : ICacheProvider
{
  private readonly IDistributedCache _distributedCache;

  public DistributedCacheProvider(IDistributedCache distributedCache)
  {
      _distributedCache = distributedCache;
  }
}

public async Task SetAsync<TKey, TValue>(TKey key, TValue value)
{ ... }

public async Task<TValue> GetAsync<TKey, TValue>(TKey key)
{ ... }
```

in startup.cs:

```
services.AddSingleton<ICacheProvider, DistributedCacheProvider>();
   
services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
{
    options.Configuration = "*******.cache.amazonaws.com:6379";
    options.InstanceName = "cache-instance-name";
});
```

Is there something I am missing in the code or some other type of configuration that needs to be done from AWS?

Comment: 6379 is the port used by Redis for non-SSL connections. Never worked with Elasticache before, but is it possible that you have in-transit encryption enabled and therefore AWS blocks non-SSL connections?

Comment: Where are you connecting to the cluster from? Have you granted external access if you are accessing it from outside the VPC?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary How to do that? Can you help me grant external access?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72133565/4800344